# Prove that $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}f(z) = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}f(\frac{1}{z})$ by definition

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I tried this:
Suppose  $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}f(z) = L_1$.
This means $\forall \epsilon_1 \ \ \exists N>0$ such that $z>N \implies |f(z) - L_1| < \epsilon_1$.

Then suppose $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}f(\frac{1}{z}) = L_2$.

This means $\forall \epsilon_{2}\ \ \exists \delta>0$ such that $0<|z|<\delta \implies |f(\frac{1}{z}) - L_2| < \epsilon_2$.

I'm not sure what to do now. Maybe I could have just done a mapping $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ but I'm not sure...

Comment: Well, if $|z|>N$ is not $|1/z|<1/N?$ Maybe $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2$ and $\delta=1/N$ works.

Comment: Actually this is wrong… it's only true iff $$\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z) = \lim_{z \to -\infty} f(z)$$ Otherwise $$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}f(\frac{1}{z})$$ doesn't exist necessarily.

Comment: @Gono Where is that needed in the proof given by Caligula or mfl?

Comment: @Gono : Nope. Note that this is in the realm of complex analysis (see tags), so there is no distinguishing $-\infty$ from $+\infty$. There is only a single point $\infty$ at infinity. On the extended real line, there are two distinct infinities. On the Riemann sphere, there is only one.

Comment: @MPW Thx… if it's really a limit on $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ you are right.

Comment: @MPW (Assume we work in the real field instead) Why does Gono's detail in the first comment not show a discrepancy in Caligula's proof? Or is there somewhere in that proof that subtly assumes that the limit on both infinite ends equal?

Comment: Your proof is incorrect as stated. The condition "$z>N$" is meaningless because there is no "$>$" for complex numbers. You would really need "$|z|>N$". But even if $z$ is assumed real, as you ask, you would need to consider the other side (i.e., $z<-N$) as well. The idea is that, for real $z$, the condition "$\frac1z\to0$" is equivalent not to "$z\to\infty$" but rather to "$z\to\infty$ or $z\to-\infty$", corresponding to $\frac1z\to0^+$ and $\frac1z\to0^-$, respectively. There are two approaches to zero, in other words, not just from the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:

$$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists N>0 :\text{ if } |z|>N \text{ then } |f(z)-L|<\epsilon$$

is equivalent to
$$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists N>0 :\text{ if } |z|<1/N \text{ then } |f(1/z)-L|<\epsilon$$

Call $\delta := 1/N$ and you are done.